# Using Javascript/jQuery is there any reason you would use YUITest over QUnit as a testing framework?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Hi i'm starting a new website and am going to be using jQuery as the library in the browser.
I was looking at testing frameworks and the obvious choice for Unit Testing in jQuery is the framework jQuery itself provides which is QUnit.

I have also looked a little at YUITest which looks very well documented. So my question is. 
If you are programming the clientside in Javascript/jQuery is there any 
reason one would use YUITest over QUnit as a testing framework?

Answer (score -1):

Yui test is providing much more features than qunit, eg. asynchronous testing and also mocking.

Also the documentation is far better.

It's really worth to have a look at Yui test.

Comment: Are you saying qunit lacks features for asynchronous testing?  From their documentation this appears not to be true.

Comment: QUnit supports asynchronous tests. You can test AJAX, pub/sub events etc. with no problem.